# What is the difficulty level of this problem?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, quadratics

I'm getting ready for the Olympiads. A week ago the teacher wanted to solve this equation. (as a task). I worked for a week, but I could not do anything.

> $$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+l=0,  (a≠0)$$

I know already this equation's solution:

$$ax^2+bx+c=0, (a≠0)$$

What is the difficulty level of this problem? What is the probability to solve this question?

If this question is against MSE rules, I am so sorry.

Comment: Solving the general quartic equation by hand will take a long time: for the method see http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

Comment: look at solving the quartic

Comment: What is the source for this problem? No sensible olympiad would like you to go through the pain of solving the quartic. Please ask your teacher if she/he has copied wrongly or has omitted certain conditions.

Comment: The teacher is probably trolling with you. The equations for solving this question won't even fit in 4 pages.

Comment: I think this is not an Olympiad question, isn't it?

Comment: Lodovico Ferrari around $1550$ AD found a formula, which to me sounds like the men on the Moon in 1969: unthinkable! You should see the way they used to write algebra at that time to understand what I mean...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Comment: @Raffaele Can the middle school student solve this equation alone?

Comment: No. Absolutely. I am a high school teacher since 1980 and I've never taught the general formula of third and fourth degree, even during the last year (18 years old students), let alone middle school! To say nothing of solving them ALONE. They should invent complex numbers from scratch... We do some special case in algebra second year (15 years old). Equation that can be factored or solved with some trick. Once I taught the bisection method to find numerical approximation during some programming classes, that's all.

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you very much, valuable teacher..